# Arithmetic mean converges almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I've been asked to show that, for a sequence of independent random variables $(X_n)$, if

$$\mathbb{P}[\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k = 1] > 0$$

then
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k \rightarrow 1$$ almost surely.

I'm really not sure how to begin. I thought it might be possible with the Borel Cantelli lemma, but the sequence of sums is not an independent sequence, which is required in the statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing to show here! This is just the _definition_ of "almost surely".

Comment: Not quite,the first line is saying that the probability is greater than zero, not that it's one. I need to show that the fact that its greater than zero implies that it is one, and therefore that its almost sure convergence

Comment: Show that the event in the first display is in the tail $\sigma$-field for the sequence $\{X_n\}_{n \geq 1}$, and then use the Kolmogorov 0-1 law.

Comment: You only have a few "zero-one laws" in your quiver, and that definitely reeks of one of them. [Kolmogorov's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law) is the most relevant -- try it.

Comment: But doesn't Kolmogorov 0-1 also require the events to be independent? These partial sums can't be independent of each other so I don't see how I'd apply this.

Comment: @Fahrenheit997 Not really. See e.g. this remark from the link above: "For example, the event that the sequence converges, and the event that its sum converges are both tail events. In an infinite sequence of coin-tosses, a sequence of 100 consecutive heads occurring infinitely many times is a tail event."
You basically are looking at Cesaro convergence of the sequence.

Comment: Right yes, I think I'd misunderstood Kolmogorov's 0-1 law. So it applies for any event in the tail algebra, not just those that are limits of independent sequences as I thought before. That makes a lot more sense, thank you!!